# Converting complex table with groupings in r to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out how to make a dataframe out of a table I made.

This is what the table looks like stored in a variable:

```
dput(t)
structure(c(83L, 197L, 8L, 67L, 220L, 1L, 108L, 176L, 4L, 32L, 
256L, 0L, 58L, 225L, 5L, 83L, 189L, 16L, 98L, 176L, 14L, 38L, 
243L, 7L, 59L, 226L, 3L, 62L, 226L, 0L, 62L, 220L, 6L, 64L, 214L, 
10L, 62L, 219L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 60L, 211L, 17L, 87L, 
161L, 40L, 32L, 254L, 2L, 31L, 243L, 14L, 31L, 230L, 27L, 49L, 
207L, 32L, 54L, 232L, 2L, 60L, 208L, 20L, 70L, 211L, 7L, 79L, 
197L, 12L, 76L, 197L, 15L, 96L, 180L, 12L, 110L, 171L, 6L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 64L, 178L, 46L, 34L, 179L, 75L, 44L, 210L, 34L, 51L, 
211L, 26L, 33L, 200L, 55L, 53L, 195L, 40L, 36L, 196L, 56L, 16L, 
258L, 14L, 39L, 217L, 32L, 40L, 209L, 39L, 44L, 211L, 33L, 28L, 
209L, 50L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 191L, 34L, 63L, 47L, 165L, 
76L, 47L, 221L, 20L, 53L, 201L, 34L, 51L, 198L, 39L, 59L, 201L, 
28L, 59L, 198L, 31L, 28L, 242L, 18L, 41L, 215L, 32L, 64L, 220L, 
4L, 65L, 212L, 11L, 28L, 182L, 77L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 45L, 229L, 14L, 
64L, 224L, 0L, 89L, 195L, 4L, 27L, 261L, 0L, 24L, 258L, 6L, 69L, 
190L, 29L, 52L, 207L, 29L, 43L, 243L, 2L, 53L, 229L, 6L, 51L, 
228L, 9L, 50L, 229L, 9L, 56L, 226L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 113L, 165L, 10L, 21L, 257L, 10L, 32L, 
244L, 12L, 36L, 236L, 16L, 44L, 211L, 33L, 26L, 258L, 4L, 38L, 
219L, 31L, 68L, 212L, 8L, 72L, 201L, 15L, 83L, 194L, 11L, 78L, 
172L, 38L, 66L, 170L, 52L, 62L, 196L, 29L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 80L, 191L, 17L, 114L, 166L, 8L, 97L, 179L, 
12L, 67L, 203L, 18L, 36L, 221L, 31L, 51L, 210L, 27L, 36L, 215L, 
37L, 45L, 205L, 38L, 37L, 213L, 38L, 20L, 250L, 18L, 42L, 233L, 
13L, 34L, 223L, 31L, 56L, 218L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
61L, 177L, 50L, 59L, 185L, 44L, 64L, 210L, 14L, 48L, 230L, 10L, 
54L, 210L, 24L, 43L, 226L, 19L, 53L, 213L, 22L, 47L, 224L, 17L, 
23L, 257L, 8L, 8L, 241L, 39L, 34L, 236L, 18L, 54L, 227L, 7L, 
45L, 221L, 21L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(3L, 30L, 8L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("Basking", "Bottom_Half", "Top_Half"), c("2017-05-21", 
    "2017-05-22", "2017-05-23", "2017-05-24", "2017-05-25", "2017-05-26", 
    "2017-05-27", "2017-05-28", "2017-05-29", "2017-05-30", "2017-05-31", 
    "2017-06-01", "2017-06-02", "2017-06-03", "2017-06-04", "2017-08-08", 
    "2017-08-09", "2017-08-10", "2017-08-11", "2017-08-12", "2017-08-13", 
    "2017-08-14", "2017-08-15", "2017-08-16", "2017-08-17", "2017-08-18", 
    "2017-08-19", "2017-08-20", "2017-08-21", "2017-08-22"), 
    c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "R1", "R2", "R3", "R4")), .Names = c("", 
"", "")), class = "table")
```

To be more specific, I used the table function to calculate the number of times Position (could be Bottom_Half, Basking, or Top_Half) was found in the turtles and on what dates. I have inserted a picture of what the table function showed.

[image]

The R2 and the R3 are 2 out of the 8 turtles that were categorized. Because of this weird table format, I'm not sure how to get it into a dataframe without manually doing it all.

Let me know if there are questions! Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can convert to data.frame with `d1 <- as.data.frame(t)`  Not clear what your expected is

Comment: Or maybe something like `apply(tab, 2, I)` ?

Comment: what output do you intend to have?

Comment: I think you should not use `table` here if it is not giving you output in usable format. Can you provide `dput` of data before using the `table` command?

Comment: @RonakShah the dput is so large that I can't copy it all from the console which is why i put it into a table.

Comment: @akrun that worked thank you! the expected output didn't matter so much because I just really wanted to get it into an excel file eventually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert to `data.frame` as

```
d1 <- as.data.frame(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `expand.grid` + `dimnames` like below

```
cbind(expand.grid(dimnames(t)), c(t))
```